# Axon Framework EventStore ReadEvents Serialization Problem

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, axon, axon-framework

5.5 and axon framework starter 4.5.4
I can read and write my events with eventhandler and queryhandler without problem
but when I want to use eventstore.readevents function I got serialization .I try to set my application properties both my reader and writer  but not working still same error(By the way I clean database and delete old events each time).I alson try to set xstream type but still same issue

```
axon.serializer.general=jackson
axon.serializer.events=jackson
axon.serializer.messages=jackson


com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.axonframework.serialization.UnknownSerializedType and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have to ask why you want to use `eventStore#readEvents` given that this is not a common usage. This method is used internally by the Framework and most of the time, should be kept like that.

To your problem, you can easily check on Framework code what is happening and how it uses the `eventStore#readEvents` method.
First of all, the signature [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/eventsourcing/src/main/java/org/axonframework/eventsourcing/eventstore/EventStore.java#L49): `DomainEventStream readEvents(String aggregateIdentifier);`

It returns a `DomainEventStream` which is an `Iterator` implementation of a `DomainEventMessage` (as you can also see on [code](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/eventsourcing/src/main/java/org/axonframework/eventsourcing/eventstore/DomainEventStream.java#L38): `public interface DomainEventStream extends Iterator<DomainEventMessage<?>> {`).

Checking any of the usages, for example the `EventSorcingRepository`, you can see how it is used [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/eventsourcing/src/main/java/org/axonframework/eventsourcing/EventSourcingRepository.java#L147) and [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/eventsourcing/src/main/java/org/axonframework/eventsourcing/EventSourcingRepository.java#L124) and pretty much use Iterator's method for that (`hasNext` and `peek` for instance).
Using those methods will give you access to the `DomainEventMessage` where you can get the `Type` but also the `Payload` (and other useful things you may need).

Hope that clarifies the usage of it but also make sure you really want to use it!

Comment: Actually I try to learn detail abilities of axon.for that reason I try different code.If using eventstore readevents not a good practice that time I dont have any specific reason to use it.thanks